# Using pound(#) in folder name, unable to open in hyperlink

Tags: windows-10, window

I've a user who has a pound(#) character in the folder name. When he adds - e.g c:\users\user1\document#myfolder as a hyperlink , he's able to open that folder.

But when he adds - e.g c:\users\user1\document#myfolder\myphotos folder as hyperlink, when heopens that folder, he got"The system cannot find the file specified"

Any idea why it's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because # in a url has a special meaning, ie jump to a position in the document.

Ive not tried it, but try using %23 in the URL instead of # - 23 being the hex value of #